# React Native: ScrollView and Layout Elements with flex

Tags: react-native, flexbox, scrollview

Hi i'm trying to add a ScrollView but it doesn't work like expected.

If i add flex:1 to ScrollView then i can style the child elements but there is no scroll bar so i can't scroll.
If I remove flex:1 or change it to flexGrow then i have the scrollbar but the styles are broken on the child elements.

How i can add i ScrollView and the styles to the childs?

I need some Information why is it happen. Thank you.

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  TextInput,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Alert,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';

import { globalStyles } from '../styles/global';
import colors from '../styles/color';

import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import Feather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';

import Button from '../components/Button';



const SignInScreen = (props) => {


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollViewContainer}>
        <View style={styles.containerTop}>
          <Text style={globalStyles.h1}>Login</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.containerBottom}>
          <View style={styles.viewAction}>
            <FontAwesome name='user-o' color='#ccc' size={20} style={{ width: 20 }} />

            <TextInput
              style={[styles.input]}
              placeholder="Your Email"
              value={data.email}
              autoCapitalize='none'
              onChangeText={(val) => textInputEmailChange(val)}
            />

          </View>

          <View style={styles.viewAction}>
            <FontAwesome name='lock' color='#ccc' size={20} style={{ width: 20 }} />

            <TextInput
              style={[styles.input]}
              placeholder="Password"
              value={data.password}
              autoCapitalize='none'
              secureTextEntry={data.secureTextEntry ? true : false}
              onChangeText={(val) => handlePasswordChange(val)}
            />

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={updateSecureTextEntry}>
              {data.secureTextEntry ? <Feather name='eye-off' color='#ccc' size={20} style={{ width: 20 }} />
                : <Feather name='eye' color='#80c904' size={20} style={{ width: 20 }} />
              }
            </TouchableOpacity>

          </View>

          {uiErrors.errors ? (<Text style={styles.errorMsg}>{uiErrors.errors}</Text>) : (<Text></Text>)}

          <Button
            content={'Login'}
            buttonStyles={{ marginVertical: 20, paddingVertical: 15, }}
            onPress={handleLogin}
          />
          <Button
            content={'Login'}
            buttonStyles={{ marginVertical: 20, paddingVertical: 15, }}
            onPress={handleLogin}
          />

          <Button
            content={'Login'}
            buttonStyles={{ marginVertical: 20, paddingVertical: 15, }}
            onPress={handleLogin}
          />

          <Button
            content={'Login'}
            buttonStyles={{ marginVertical: 20, paddingVertical: 15, }}
            onPress={handleLogin}
          />
          <Button
            content={'Login'}
            buttonStyles={{ marginVertical: 20, paddingVertical: 15, }}
            onPress={handleLogin}
          />

          <Button
            content={'Create an account'}
            buttonStyles={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
            textStyles={styles.signUpBtnText}
            onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('SignUp'); }}
          />

        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: colors.light_theme.splashgb,
  },
  scrollViewContainer: {
    // flex: 1,
    // flexGrow: 1,
    // justifyContent: 'space-between'
  },
  containerTop: {
    flex: 1, // it add this only if flex:1 is added to scrollViewContainer but the then i can't scroll.
    padding: 25,
    backgroundColor: 'blue'
  },
  containerBottom: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 25,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: colors.light_theme.container,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 25,
    borderTopRightRadius: 25,
  },

  viewAction: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: '100%',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: colors.light_theme.lightgray,
    paddingVertical: 0,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  input: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 15,
  },

  text: {
    color: colors.light_theme.white,
  },
  errorMsg: {
    color: colors.light_theme.errorMsg,
    fontSize: 14,
    marginVertical: 5,
  },

  signUpBtnText: {
    color: colors.light_theme.primary
  }

});

export default SignInScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

**1:** Put your ScrollView inside a View:

```
... <View><ScrollView> ... </ScrollView></View> ...
```

**2:** Remove "flex:1" from your scrollViewContainer style so it will be only with felxGrow and justifyContent

Comment: it is already wrapped in a view... or how do you mean it?

Comment: In my project I had a list on the top which I wanted to scroll in that and a button at the end which I wanted to act like a footer. So it came out like this: `<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <View style={{flex: 9}}>
    <ScrollView style={{flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: "center">
    MY List
    <ScrollView />
    </View>
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      My Button
  </View>
</View>`